# Attache order as pdf is not display in fooman extension magneto version 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, admin, extensions, magento2.3.1

I used Magento version 2.3.1. I installed extension fooman version 104.0.3. In the admin side, I am not able to see a checkbox for `Attache order as pdf`

Here I attached its screenshot. [image]

You can see that the checkbox option is missing. This extension is working perfectly in 2.2.6. Now I want to run it in 2.3.1 latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. The missing dropdown would indicate that you are missing the Print Order Pdf extension (or it's not enabled).
2. Version 104.0.3 is not compatible with Magento 2.3.1 - seeing that you were able to upgrade to 2.3.1 this would indicate that you are not using Composer to manage the installation. I suggest deleting app/code/Fooman and install as per our installation guides (latest version is 105.0.8).

Comment: why so complex installation process?

Comment: so you don't end up with a version combination that doesn't work

Comment: Send me its compatible version with Magento 2.3.1. @KristofatFooman